How to query navigation property of IdentityRole in EF Core
Background:
I create a custom Role class extends the IdentityRole:
public class Role:IdentityRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }// store the Menu Role can access
}

I want to know how to load the MenuItems object when i retrieve the role object.
Firstly, i try to use the FindByUdAsync method, but not work.
await var role =_roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId)

Then i try to use the include method, but the DBSet<Roles> not support the include method
_context.Roles.Include(r=>r.MenuItems)


I don't know where "roleId" come from. If your code have no mistake ,you can try to use "_context.Roles.Include(r=>r.MenuItems).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == roleId)".
If your problem is not resolved, you can check  "rolemanager"  is type of RoleManager or RoleManager?  You can share more code shippet of dbcontext and  registered identity in program.cs and some error message.
